# Find the largest node of each segment in a series of paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to divide different short chains according to the head and tail I want in a long chain, and find the max duration in the short chains.

E.g..

Long chain:

NA1 -> NA2 -> NA3 -> NA4 -> NB1 -> NB2 -> NB3 -> NB4 ->...

I want to check whether the max duration in each chain is the second node.

NA1 -> NA2 -> NA3 -> NA4

NB1 -> NB2 -> NB3 -> NB4

...

( N means node, A,b and the number are the attribute and each node has its own duration )

```
MATCH p = (A:Task{FROMLOCTYPE:"1"})-[:path*]->(b:Task{TOLOCTYPE:"4"})

WITH reduce(output = [], n IN nodes(p) | output + n ) as tasks
```

But I'm stuck here and don't know how to check the maximum duration in each list.

Or do any operation in each list.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question ...what is A & B ?  Can you give a concrete example ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for, but here is an example on how to find the item with a max value plus its position in the array :

```
MATCH p = (A:Task{FROMLOCTYPE:"1"})-[:path*]->(b:Task{TOLOCTYPE:"4"})
WITH 
    reduce(
        output = [0, 0, 0], 
        n IN nodes(p) |  
        CASE 
            WHEN output[0] < n.duration THEN [n.duration, output[2], output[2]+1]
            ELSE [output[0], output[1], output[2]+1]
    ) as tasks
 RETURN 
  tasks[0] AS max,
  tasks[1] AS positionInArray
```

In the reduce we create an array with 3 elements :

- in the first one we will store the maximum value found
- in the second the position in the array of the maximum value
- in the third, it's just an increment to track the position of where we are in the array

A good read about that : https://blog.armbruster-it.de/2015/03/cypher-fun-finding-the-position-of-an-element-in-an-array/

Comment: Thank for your reply. I fixed the unclear description of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKq9W.png)

> MATCH p = (A:Task{FROMLOCTYPE:"LOAD_PORT"})-[:wafer_path*]->(b:Task{TOLOCTYPE:"LOAD_PORT"})
> return p limit 3

The photo is my sample data.

Sorry my previous description was not clear enough.

I think my problem should be when I find a bunch of lists.

How do I search these nodes at the same time.

A bit like how to find the maximum value of an array in a two-dimensional array.

I can group nodes according to the classification I want.

> MATCH p = (A:Task{FROMLOCTYPE:"LOAD_PORT"})-[:wafer_path*]->(b:Task{TOLOCTYPE:"LOAD_PORT"})
> return p

P will return all the Ps that Neo4j finds.

And the nodes in p has its own duration.

> [12,18,14,15]
>
> [15,19,12,11]
>
> [12,15,13,14]

But I ’m not sure how to query for the max duration in each group with cypher.
Or check the MAX duration node is (Task:{position:"2")

Thank again for your reply.